# Rails has_secure_password - either no blankness validation or two validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a simple ActiveRecord model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[\w\-._]*[\w\-_]\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :password, 
                    presence: true, 
                    length: { minimum: 6 }

  before_save { email.downcase! }
  has_secure_password
end
```

So here is my problem.

1) If I leave "presence: true" in my password vaildation and leave password field empty, when I push "Create" button in my form, I have TWO identical 'password is blank' errors instead of one.

2) If I leave "presence: true" in my password vaildation and fill password field with spaces, I have only one 'password is blank' error.

3) If I comment out presence vaildation and leave password field empty, I have one 'password is blank' error.

4) If I comment out presence vaildation and fill password field with spaces, I have no errors!

I want to have only ONE error - both for empty field and field full of spaces. I could make hacks like @user.errors.full_messages.uniq.each and so on, but I do not want to.

Is there a way to make has_secure_password behave like I want?..

Comment: Try removing `validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }`

Comment: Nope, still accepting spaces. Also, I want to reject too short passwords, and with simple `validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }` I have 3) and 4) behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an option to `has_secure_password` to skip its built-in validations and use your own:

```
has_secure_password(validations: false)
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/869a90512f36b04914d73cbf58317d953caea7c5/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L66